# PHP array values with SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

In PHP, I want to execute a SQL query passing array values along with the SQL statement. I can't manage to do this.

Please consider the following

```
$db = "mydatabase.sqlite";
$array = array(
              "key1" => "value1",
              "key2" => "value2",
              "key3" => "value3"
         );

try {

    $dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:$db");
    $dbhandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    foreach ($array as $item) {

      $timestamp = 
      $dbhandle->exec(
              "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (field1, field2, field3) 
                   VALUES ('$item['key1']', '$item['key2']', '$item['key3']')"
              );
      $dbhandle = NULL;

    } 

  } 

catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Exception : ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
  }
```

How to express the SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When interpolating array elements into a string, don't put quotes around the key:

```
          "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (field1, field2, field3) 
               VALUES ('$item[key1]', '$item[key2]', '$item[key3]')"
```

or use the "complex" syntax with curly braces:

```
          "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (field1, field2, field3) 
               VALUES ('{$item['key1']}', '{$item['key2']}', '{$item['key3']}')"
```

However, it would be better to use a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $dbhandle->prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (field1, field2, field3)
                            VALUES (:key1, :key2, :key3)");
$stmt->execute($item);
```

Comment: technically correct, but @CptNemo please use prepared statements instead; using for example `$pdoStmt->bindValue( ':key1', $item['key1'] )` escapes the inputs while respecting the DB data type and you could use the default array notation…